# cURL retry in PHP

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Is it possible to set the option to  retry on timeouts in PHP cURL?

I know I can do this by coding it to retry on failure, just wondering if there's some way to do it through an option.

Comment: [lisy of all the curl options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: the best way would be to retry on failure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with the current options available to the PHP cURL extension. On the command line I believe there is the `--retry` option, but that is not exposed to PHP.

Answer (score 30):

you can use the errno to retry like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$retry = 0;
while(curl_errno($curl) == 28 && $retry < 3){
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $retry++;
}

$error_codes=array(
    [1] => 'CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL', 
    [2] => 'CURLE_FAILED_INIT', 
    [3] => 'CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT', 
    [4] => 'CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT_USER', 
    [5] => 'CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY', 
    [6] => 'CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST', 
    [7] => 'CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT', 
    [8] => 'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_SERVER_REPLY',
    [9] => 'CURLE_REMOTE_ACCESS_DENIED',
    [11] => 'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_PASS_REPLY',
    [13] => 'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_PASV_REPLY',
    [14]=>'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_227_FORMAT',
    [15] => 'CURLE_FTP_CANT_GET_HOST',
    [17] => 'CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_SET_TYPE',
    [18] => 'CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE',
    [19] => 'CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_RETR_FILE',
    [21] => 'CURLE_QUOTE_ERROR',
    [22] => 'CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR',
    [23] => 'CURLE_WRITE_ERROR',
    [25] => 'CURLE_UPLOAD_FAILED',
    [26] => 'CURLE_READ_ERROR',
    [27] => 'CURLE_OUT_OF_MEMORY',
    [28] => 'CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT',
    ....
```

Comment: It's better to use do {} while () to avoid code duplicates (in case the loop body contains several lines of logic)

Comment: If the problem persists, it may also be a good idea to add a `sleep($delay)` in the loop, to increase the chances that a network congestion clears up inbetween retries.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make my file download function be resumable, here's what i've come up with. using `fstat()` to get what was downloaded and feed that value to curl on failure using the `CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM` option.

```php
function download_file(string $url): ?string
{
    $name = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), time() . ".tmp");
    $out = fopen($name, 'a+');
    start_over:
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Utils::make_curl_headers());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);

        // TODO: SSL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, fstat($out)['size']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, $delayed_progress);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, bytes("64kb"));
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch) !== 0) {
            fwrite(STDOUT, "  ERROR: " . (curl_error($ch) ?? "CONNECTION_ERROR") 
              . ", will try again in 10 seconds..." . PHP_EOL);
            sleep(10);
            goto start_over;
        }
    }
    return $name;
}
```